# Finding the equation of a line perpendicular to a curve at a given point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation of the perpendicular line of $y=e^{-2x^2}$ at the point where $x=1$.

I found the derivative: $y'=e^{-x^2}-2x$. And when I plug in one to the derivative I get: $m=\frac{1}{e}-2$.

I found the negative reciprocal because it's asking for the perpendicular line so: $m=-e+\frac{1}{2}$.

Then I put it in the point-slope formula: $y-\frac{1}{e}=(-e+\frac{1}{2})(x-1)$.

I tried solving but no matter how I try to simplify I can't come up with the correct answer: $$y=\frac{e}{2}x+\frac{1}{e}-\frac{e}{2}.$$

I was wondering if I messed up somewhere along the way? And if not would someone mind giving me a hint on simplifying to get the correct answer?

Comment: You computed the derivative incorrectly; it should be $y'=-4xe^{-2x^2}$.

Comment: The derivative should be $y' = e^{-2x^2} \cdot (-2x^2)' = -4xe^{-2x^2}$.

Comment: ahh of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule, $$y' = -4xe^{-2x^2}$$

The slope of the tangent line at the point $x=1$ is then $$m = -4e^{-2} = \frac{-4}{e^2}$$

The slope of the line perpendicular at the point $x = 1$ is thus $$m_\bot = \frac {e^2}{4}$$

Can you take it from here?